# How to listen multiple queue in single microservice?

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs, microservices, nestjs-microservice

```
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.RMQ,
      options: {
        urls: [
          `amqp ://${process.env.RABITMQ_USERNAME}:${process.env.RABITMQ_PASSWORD}@${process.env.RABITMQ_HOST}:${process.env.RABITMQ_PORT}`,
        ],
        queue: 'master_ms_locale',
        noAck: false,
        queueOptions: {
          durable: false,
        },
      },
    },
  );
  
  await app.listen();
```

**In above I need another queue that will listen master_ms_country as well**